# How to disable unused roles in AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have some roles in my Dev account that has not been used for over 90days and I would like to disable those role for now without deleting them.

please how do i write the policy that i can attach to those roles that will deny all actions to all resources in AWS account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To temporarily disable a user, you can go via 2 options which i'll outline below:

1. Apply a restrictive IAM policy
2. Disable their console and access keys to AWS

**Option 1:**

Explicit denies applied via AWS IAM policies overrides any allow permissions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

> Remember, an explicit deny in any of these policies overrides the allow.

So your newly attached policy should just include a deny all for all resources and actions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllActions",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Option 2:**

Although another thing you can do is disable the IAM keys and remove console access so that you effectively disable the user without applying any restrictive permissions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

> To disable an active access key, choose Make inactive.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_controlling-access.html

> You can disable user access to the AWS Management Console by removing their password. This prevents them from signing into the AWS Management Console using their user name and password